# run function after eventlistener finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, three.js

I have the following code that checks if there is a gyroscope available for the user to interact with. I do this in the following way:

```
function check_user_hardware(){
    window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
        if(event.rotationRate.alpha || event.rotationRate.beta || event.rotationRate.gamma){
            if (!gyroscope) {
                gyroscope = true;
                current_interaction_mode = 'gyroscope_option';
                set_user_ui_elements();
            }
        }else{
            followMouse = true;
            current_interaction_mode = 'followMouse_option';
            console.log("checked for motion");
            set_user_ui_elements();
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', get_user_mouse_pos);
        }
        calculate_rotation_mesh_pos(event.rotationRate.beta, event.rotationRate.gamma);
    }, function(){
        console.log("generate_scene???");
        generate_scene();
    });
}
```

the problem i am having is that after this check some scene is generated.
But this scene requires a var to be set first first in the check. But the check takes to long so i added a callback after the check is completed.
But this callback never fires... Why? In other words `generate_scene???` is never logged and `generate_scene();` is never run.

Why is this happening? and what would be the proper way to do this?

if anything is unclear please let me know so i can clarify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is next: the third parameter in your .addEventListener method is function, it shouldn't be, because in documentation third parameter is Boolean if exactly "useCapture".
Try to declare generate_scene function out of check_user_hardware() and then just call it after

```
calculate_rotation_mesh_pos(event.rotationRate.beta,event.rotationRate.gamma);
generate_scene();
```

It might work.